# How to set a transparent image in particular image in Android?

Tags: android

I'm using a `plus`/`minus` button to increase and decrease image transparency:

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    selectGhostDialog = new Dialog(MainActivity.this);
    selectGhostDialog.setContentView(R.layout.gridview_layout);
    selectGhostDialog.setTitle("select ghost");
    gridview = (GridView) selectGhostDialog.findViewById(R.id.gridview);
    gridview.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(MainActivity.this));
    gridview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v,
                        final int position, long id) {

            photoSorter.loadImages1(MainActivity.this,
                        Constant.mThumbIds[position]);
            selectGhostDialog.dismiss();
            imgBtnundo.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            photoSorter.unloadImages(MainActivity.this,
                                    Constant.mThumbIds[position]);
                        }
                    });
                }
            });
            selectGhostDialog.show();
        }
    });
```

Please help me on setting this transparency from `photoposter class` using that class method.

Comment: used `ImageView.getBackground.setAlpha(value)`; alpha values 0-255

Comment: but i have using photoposter class for zoom in zoom out and i have no idea which method call for tranperent